# JavaScript functions messing up my Radio Button displays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, radio-button

I created a form which contains two Radio Buttons.

Each radio button displays a separate form, when Clicked.

When a button is un-clicked, the form disappears from view  (it is not shown)

I also added a second JavaScript Function, which disables the "**SUBMIT**" button, if none of the radio buttons are clicked.

The program works fine..........except I have the following problems :

(a)  For some reason, I am able to click BOTH radio buttons!  Radio-buttons should not allow for more than one selection. But, in my form, **both radio buttons are clickable**

(b)  the second JS function is not working;  disabling the SUBMIT button is easy. But...........when I click either of the radio buttons, **the SUBMIT button does not enable.**

Here is the first JS function (for "hiding" the forms under each radio buttons)

```
      <script        
     src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
     </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function displayForm(c) {
            if (c.value == "2") {    
                jQuery('#firstformContainer').toggle('show');
                jQuery('#secondformContainer').hide();
            }
                if (c.value == "1") {
                 jQuery('#secondformContainer').toggle('show');
                 jQuery('#firstformContainer').hide();
            }
        };
        </script>
```

And the second function, for disabling the SUBMIT button :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function fCheck() { 
         document.my_form.submit.disabled 
         =!(document.my_form.formselector1.checked ||       
 document.my_form.formselector2.checked); 
         } 
 </script>
```

And here is the form :

```
    <form name="my_form" id="my_form">
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" 
    id="formselector1" onClick="displayForm(this); fCheck()"></input>Input 
     Firstname
            <div style="display:none" id="firstformContainer">
                <form id="firstform"> 
                            <input type="text" "16" id="firstname" 
      name="firstname" value="$firstname">
                        </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" 
       id="formselector2" onClick="displayForm(this); fCheck()">
       </input>Input Surname
            <div style="display:none" id="secondformContainer">
                <form id="secondform">
                    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" 
        value="$surname">
                </dd>
                </form>
            </div>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="REGISTER" disabled>
       </form>
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I have solved the **RADIO BUTTON** problem.

Now, I need to fix the second problem, with the JS function :  **fCheck ()**

It is not working.

I have feeling it's because :  I am not calling BOTH functions correctly in the **ONCLICK**.

```
   <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" id="radio1"   
   onClick="displayForm(this); javascript:fCheck()"></input>

   <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" id="radio2" 
   onClick="displayForm(this); javascript:fCheck()"></input>
```

Comment: you need to make the `name` attribute the same for both radios. that links them together, so to speak.

Comment: They are both the same :  "formselector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest forms. This makes the second radio button not inside the form and hence it allows you to select both at the same time. Rewrite your html like this

```
<form name="my_form" id="my_form">
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" id="formselector1" onClick="displayForm(this); fCheck()"></input>
    <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" id="formselector2" onClick="displayForm(this); fCheck()"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="REGISTER" disabled>
</form>
Input Firstname
<div style="display:none" id="firstformContainer">
    <form id="firstform"> 
        <input type="text" "16" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="$firstname">
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
Input Surname            
<div style="display:none" id="secondformContainer">
    <form id="secondform">
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="$surname">
    </form>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you, Bharani.  Your code was not exactly accurate;  the SUBMIT button should still be at the bottom (as I posted). Otherwise, it appears at the top of the form.  But, still, your answer put me on the right track, so thanks :=))))

Comment: However, my second JS function is not working. I feel the reason is :  I am not calling BOTH functions correctly in the "ONCLICK"   (I have updated my question to include this)

Comment: @phpnewbie2015 why do you want 3 forms? I would consolidate them to a single form and show hide the input boxes according to the radio button selected. This will also fix your problem of needing the submit button at the bottom. If at all you need all 3 forms then you should use css to format the submit button. fCheck() worked the way you had it. Debug in Chrome/firebug to see what errors you get.